# Saving multiple PDF letters in specific person name folders

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, mailmerge

Hoping someone can help or point me in the right direction. I have thousands of letters in a single folder that I will generate via mail merge (from Excel, Word then pdf). In the Excel source file I have a column with the line manager name that I have used separate VBA code to create separate folders.

I now need to save these letters in specific folders as per employee's line manager name. So for example if letter has John Doe as line manager - the code will lookup John Doe in the list of folders and if found saves the letter in that specific folder.

Thanks

Comment: See *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Hi PEH, macropod - Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the 'Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files'

Comment: Hi PEH, macropod - Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the 'Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files' available on above thread. This does work in saving the .pdf file but was wondering how I can adapt this so that it creates as folder first (eg Joe Doe folder)  then drops the .pdf in that folder. Maybe this is not possible at all?